# Original IP address when using a VPN

Tags: vpn

Can the web site I'm visiting via a VPN "look through" the IP address supplied by the VPN to learn the IP address I'm using to connect to the VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically the web server. The VPN pretty much grabs the website for you, and then the VPN sends it too you (more or less), but it IS possible to uncover IPs behind a VPN - however only extremely skilled technicians, network operators or other organisations (cough, FBI) have the utilities, knowledge, time and power (compute power, etc.) to do this, as most VPNs usually encrypt traffic.

Also note that court orders against the VPN company can also force them to give up your information, which includes your IP(s).

Comment: So ... if my VPN provider encrypts its traffic the likelihood is extremely low?

Comment: That's correct. Just keep in mind that depending on the TOS of the VPN and how much data they collect on you, they can always be court ordered by an international security organisation from any (most) countries for said data which MAY contain your IP. Depends on the TOS.